# Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I want to display my data/product by category in frontend with URL/slug. I watch on YouTube, but I'm stuck when I click URL/link category got an error like this.

> ErrorException
> **Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\e-catalog\resources\views\frontend\layouts\header.blade.php)**

This is my header.blade.php:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/goldmart" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Goldmart</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach ($gmcategories as $gmc )
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('goldmart/'.$gmc->slug)}}">{{$gmc->category_name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/goldmart', 'GoldmartController@index');
Route::get('/goldmart/{slug}', 'GoldmartController@readCategory');
```

This is my Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gmproducts;
use App\Gmcategories;

class GoldmartController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $gmproducts   = Gmproducts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        $gmcategories   = Gmcategories::all();

        return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'gmcategories'));
    }

    public function readCategory($slug)
    {
        $category = Gmcategories::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $gmcategories = Gmcategories::all();
        if($gmcategories)
        {
            $gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $gmcategories->id)->get();
            return view('frontend.pages.goldmart', compact('gmproducts', 'category', 'gmcategories'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return view('frontend.pages.goldmart');
    }
}
```

My AppServiceProvider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        // Membuat penulisan currency
        Blade::directive('currency', function ($expression)
        {
            return "Rp<?php echo number_format($expression,2,',','.'); ?>";
        });

        View::composer('frontend.layouts.header', function ($view) {
            $view->with('gmcategories', Gmcategories::all());
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: One or more of the `$gmc` variables in your `@foreach` loop is not an object.

Comment: What do I have to do?

Comment: You need to debug your code, put a `dd($gmcategories);` in your controller and see what value you're getting back from the database. Then go from there.

Comment: does your `header.blade.php` display all the pages or only one of them?

Comment: @Peppermintology I tried this and I put above the result. I don't know what I have to do with that.

Comment: @JSTECH display all the pages. I want to display my products by category when I click some category.

Comment: does your header.blade.php `$gmcategories ` and controller `$gmcategories` data depend each other? I mean their data should equal to each other or can be different?

Comment: could you add a screenshot of your category attributes?

Comment: @JSTECH I'm sorry I don't understand, but you can see my full controller above.

Comment: Your are passing `$gmcategories` to view  `frontend.pages.goldmart` but it also replace the value of `$gmcategories` in `header.blade.php` because both the view file are using same `$gmcategories` data.

Comment: @Joseph You can see above.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: @MyBuzynis I'm waiting for your confirmation from yesterday of what you're doing but that's exactly what I was going to answer to you `View::composer(...)`. Thanks to @Joseph, he answered before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change controller from this:

```
$gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $gmcategories->id)->get();
```

To this:

```
$gmproducts = Gmproducts::where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('gm/'.($gmc->slug ?? null)) }}">
{{$gmc->category_name}}
</a>
</li>


**You can also try this one**
<li>
@if($gmc->slug)
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('gm/'.($gmc->slug ?? '#')) }}">
{{$gmc->category_name}}
</a>
@else
slug not found
@endif
</li>
```